# CSS Style not applied after redirect in Icefaces 3 application on IE8 web browser

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, icefaces-3

I have an application implemented with JSF2 and Icefaces3 where I have problems in the stylesheets application. At the login the style sheet applies correctly, but after each redirection it's no longer correct. This problem is found only with IE browser. In the faces-config.xml file when I remove the redirect tag (), everything is ok except that the URL does not change and it does not take into account the tag:  that I added to force compatibility mode. For the import of the stylesheet I have tried several formula:

```
    <!-- formule 1-->
    <ice:outputStyle
            href="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/css/global.css"
            rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

   <!-- formule 2-->
    <ice:outputStyle
                href="#{request.contextPath}/resources/css/global.css"
                rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!-- formule 3-->
    <ice:outputStyle
                href="/resources/css/global.css"
                rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

     <!-- formule 4-->
    <link href="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/css/global.css" rel="styleSheet" type="text/css"/>

     <!-- formule 5-->
     <link href="#{request.contextPath}/resources/css/global.css" rel="styleSheet" type="text/css"/>
```

faces-config.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <application>
        <variable-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingVariableResolver</variable-resolver>
        <variable-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.SpringBeanVariableResolver</variable-resolver>
        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver> 
    </application>

    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>renderManager</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.icesoft.faces.async.render.RenderManager</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>application</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>

    <factory>
        <exception-handler-factory>
            com.omb.exception.CustomExceptionHandlerFactory
        </exception-handler-factory>
    </factory>

    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>*</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>homeHotel</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/pages/home/home.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect />
        </navigation-case>

        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>disconnect</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect />
        </navigation-case>

        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>error</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/pages/errors/technicalError.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect />
        </navigation-case>

        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>sessionExpired</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>login.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>

</faces-config>
```

web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
  "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
  "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>

    <display-name>MyApplication</display-name>
    <description>MyApplication</description>

    <!-- Without this param upload does not work at 1st time with IceFaces 3.3.0 -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.icefaces.mandatoryResourceConfiguration</param-name>
        <param-value>all</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/pages/templates/tags.taglib.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/appCtx/**/*applicationContext*.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>


    <!-- Facelet Config -->
    <!-- <context-param> <param-name>javax.faces.application.CONFIG_FILES</param-name> 
        <param-value> /WEB-INF/faces-config-application-beans.xml, /WEB-INF/faces-config-navigation.xml 
        </param-value> </context-param> -->
    <!-- <context-param> <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name> 
        <param-value>Development</param-value> </context-param> -->

    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
        <param-value>-1</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.standardRequestScope</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Specifies to the ICEfaces framework whether to support multiple views 
        of a single application from the same browser. When running in a Portlet 
        environment, this parameter must be set to true. -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.concurrentDOMViews</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Specifies to the ICEfaces framework that synchronous update mode is 
        to be used. By default, ICEfaces uses asynchronous update mode to support 
        server-initiated updates (AJAX push). Setting to true will enable synchronous 
        update mode and disable AJAX push features. -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.synchronousUpdate</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Specifies to the ICEfaces framework whether to compress the server-side 
        DOM representation after each response. This saves a considerable amount 
        of of memory per client. However, since this is decompressed/compressed for 
        every update, it may not bring significant memory savings to applications 
        that make frequent use of AJAX push. -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.compressDOM</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Specifies the amount of time in milliseconds that the bridge will wait 
        for a response from the server for a user-initiated request before declaring 
        the connection lost. Un-comment and change the default value, if necessary. -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.connectionTimeout</param-name>
        <param-value>300000</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <!-- Specifies the amount of time in milliseconds that an idle asynchronous 
        blocking connection should be held open before being released. Normally, 
        the blocking connection is closed and re-opened with every communication 
        to the browser, such as user interaction or a heartbeat ping. The purpose 
        of this setting is to remove the possibility of threads being held blocked 
        for a long duration on a dead or completely inactive client connection. This 
        value should be longer than the heartbeat interval to avoid unnecessary network 
        traffic. Un-comment and change the default value, if necessary. -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>
            com.icesoft.faces.blockingConnectionTimeout
        </param-name>
        <param-value>90000</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <!-- Specifies the amount of time in milliseconds between heartbeat messages. 
        Un-comment and change the default value, if necessary. -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.heartbeatInterval</param-name>
        <param-value>50000</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <!-- Specifies how many consecutive heartbeat connection attempts may fail 
        before the connection is considered lost. Un-comment and change the default 
        value, if necessary. -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.heartbeatRetries</param-name>
        <param-value>2</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <!-- Specifies the number of milliseconds that a heartbeat request waits 
        for a successful response before it is considered timed out. Un-comment and 
        change the default value, if necessary. -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.heartbeatTimeout</param-name>
        <param-value>60000</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <!-- Specifies a page URI to redirect the client to when an asynchronous 
        connection is lost. The parameter value must be surrounded by single quotes. 
        Un-comment and change the default value, if necessary. -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>
            com.icesoft.faces.connectionLostRedirectURI
        </param-name>
        <param-value>login.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>
            com.icesoft.faces.sessionExpiredRedirectURI
        </param-name>
        <param-value>login.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.blockUIOnSubmit</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.icefaces.ace.fileEntry.requireJavascript</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jExposeWebAppRoot</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter
        </filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>singleSession</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- <filter-mapping> <filter-name>loggedInFilter</filter-name> <url-pattern>/pages/*</url-pattern> 
        </filter-mapping> -->

    <!-- SPRING -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.util.IntrospectorCleanupListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Listener d'initialisation de l'application -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.omb.listeners.MyServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Faces Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.icesoft.faces.webapp.CompatResourceServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/icefaces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/xmlhttp/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <!-- Welcome files -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/pages/error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.RuntimeException</exception-type>
        <location>/pages/error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

login.xhtml :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
    xmlns:ace="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/components"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
    <!--  ice:outputStyle href="/resources/css/global.css" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css" /-->
    <ice:outputStyle
        href="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/css/myCss.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</h:head>

<h:body onload='document.getElementById("loginForm:login").focus()'>
    <ice:form id="loginForm">

        <h:panelGroup id="page" styleClass="mainMaster" layout="block">
            <h:panelGroup id="header" styleClass="header" layout="block">
                <h:panelGroup styleClass="logo" layout="block">
                    <ice:graphicImage styleClass="imgLogo"
                        value="/resources/images/common/logo/Logo.png" />
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:panelGroup id="content" styleClass="mainContent" layout="block">
                <h:panelGroup styleClass="content" layout="block">
                    <h:panelGroup styleClass="txtLogin" layout="block">
                        <span><ice:outputLabel value="#{msg['login']}" /> : * </span>
                        <ice:inputText value="#{loginBean.login}" id="login" />
                    </h:panelGroup>
                    <h:panelGroup styleClass="txtLogin" layout="block">
                        <span><ice:outputLabel value="#{msg['password']}" /> : *</span>
                        <ice:inputSecret value="#{loginBean.password}"
                            action="#{loginBean.doLogin}" />
                        <br />
                        <span></span>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                    <h:panelGroup styleClass="txtLogin" layout="block">
                        <span></span>
                        <ice:commandButton id="loginButton" value="#{msg['log.on']}"
                            action="#{loginBean.doLogin}" />
                    </h:panelGroup>
                    <h:panelGroup layout="block">
                        <ace:panel style="border: 0px;">
                            <ace:message id="formMsg" for="loginForm" initEffect="slide" />
                        </ace:panel>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:panelGroup id="footer" styleClass="footer" layout="block">
                <ui:insert name="footer">
                    <ui:include src="/pages/layer/footer/footer.xhtml" />
                </ui:insert>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </ice:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

template.xhtml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component">

<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
    <title><ui:insert name="title">MyApplication</ui:insert></title>
    <ice:outputStyle href="/xmlhttp/css/xp/xp.css" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css" />
    <!--  ice:outputStyle href="#{request.contextPath}/resources/css/global.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /-->
    <ice:outputStyle
        href="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/css/global.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jsf.ajax.addOnError(function(data) {
            if (data.responseText.indexOf("SessionExpiredException") > 0) {
                window.location = "login.xhtml";
            }
        });

        // French initialization
        ice.ace.locales['fr'] = {
            closeText : 'Fermer',
            prevText : 'Précédent',
            nextText : 'Suivant',
            currentText : 'Courant',
            monthNames : [ 'Janvier', 'Février', 'Mars', 'Avril', 'Mai',
                    'Juin', 'Juillet', 'Août', 'Septembre', 'Octobre',
                    'Novembre', 'Décembre' ],
            monthNamesShort : [ 'Jan', 'Fév', 'Mar', 'Avr', 'Mai', 'Jun',
                    'Jul', 'Aoû', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Déc' ],
            dayNames : [ 'Dimanche', 'Lundi', 'Mardi', 'Mercredi', 'Jeudi',
                    'Vendredi', 'Samedi' ],
            dayNamesShort : [ 'Dim', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mer', 'Jeu', 'Ven', 'Sam' ],
            dayNamesMin : [ 'Di', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Me', 'Je', 'Ve', 'Sa' ],
            weekHeader : 'Sm',
            dateFormat : 'dd/mm/yy',
            firstDay : 1,
            isRTL : false,
            showMonthAfterYear : false,
            yearSuffix : ''
        };
    </script>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:panelGroup id="page" styleClass="mainMaster" layout="block">
        <h:panelGroup id="header" styleClass="header" layout="block">
            <ui:insert name="header">
                <ui:include
                    src="/pages/layer/header/#{contextBean.templateHeaderName}" />
            </ui:insert>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup id="headerMenu" styleClass="menu" layout="block">
            <ui:insert name="buttons">
                <ui:include
                    src="/pages/layer/menu/#{contextBean.templateMenuButtonName}" />
            </ui:insert>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup id="main" styleClass="mainContent" layout="block">
            <h:panelGroup id="content" styleClass="content" layout="block">
                <h:panelGroup layout="block"
                    rendered="#{not facesContext.validationFailed and not empty facesContext.messageList}">
                    <h:messages id="psuedoGlobalMessages" globalOnly="true"
                        infoStyle="color:blue" errorStyle="color:red"
                        warnClass="color:orange" showDetail="false" showSummary="true" />
                </h:panelGroup>
                <ui:insert name="content" />
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup id="footer" styleClass="footer" layout="block">
            <ui:insert name="footer">
                <ui:include src="/pages/layer/footer/footer.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :

- First I changed the implementation of the login.xhtml page so that it includes also in my Facelet template.
- Second : I added the DOCTYPE balise at the beginning of the template.xhtml

Now the sheetstyle is applied in all pages.

For the compatibility mode i made a HttpFilter which set attribute :

```
((HttpServletResponse) response).setHeader("X-UA-Compatible", this.xuacompatible);
```